# Call Web API JSON webservice from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: json, sql-server, webapi

I am trying to find a way to call a web API web service that returns JSON from a SQL Server stored procedure. I have found ways to call SOAP web services but not web services that return JSONn.
Also the web service requires authentication with username and passwd.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLR (Common Language Runtime) SQL Server objects which enables programming in .NET within SQL Server

I used once created and used a [CLR split function in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-string-split-tsql-clr-function-sample.aspx)

Comment: How are you going to add a CLR on the cloud? for example Azure?

Comment: With limitations, it is possible to write and use CLR in Azure.
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/clr-assemblies-azure-sql-database

Comment: I found this example http://blog.davebouwman.com/2008/07/09/call-geonames-web-services-from-a-sql-stored-procedure/ and with a few modification you can use json, instead of xml. My next problem is, how you would make this service call with a Token in header (if the web service requires that), or with username and password in body?

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis The link is not working. I am also looking for similar solution.